# Add All link on view pager

Tags: views, paging

Is there a way to add a  Show All Link on my view pager.

I have a Block View.

I would like to be able to add an All Link button when the number of Items reach 5. I do not need the pager "Next, last 1,2,3" only the All Link button.

Thanks a lot

Comment: see my edit(s) to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes see the `Pager Options` for your Block or Views Page:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Allow me to clarify. This gets the `- All -` text option into the configuration of the View. If you want custom business logic that says if there is 5 or more results I want to show/hide the Next and Previous and include the All options I recommend you look at `hook_views_pre_view()` or other Views hooks to implement hiding/removing options as needed. For ease I recommend hiding/showing the options using CSS or Javascript.

Again, this option builds the option into the page -- but doesn't really enforce your business logic.

**EDIT 2:**

The module [Pagerer](https://www.drupal.org/project/pagerer) might get you a little further, but probably not all of your custom logic is possible out of the box with that module. It has an API to fine-grain it's custom pager views.

Comment: Can you provide me a sample code for Edit One. ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this via coding then this can be helpful to you. I've used this in my own projects.

1. Add a new file with ".views.inc" extension. Preferred module_name.views.inc.
2. Theme the block form and add a variable to the views output via HOOK [views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7).
3. Then with the HOOK_pre_build function you can modify the pager items per page.

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name = 'your_view') {
    $view->attachment_after['show_all'] = l('Title', 'show-all', array('query' => array('view_name' => $view->name)));
  }
}


function MYMODULE_views_pre_build(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'your_view' && (isset($_GET['view_name']) && $_GET['view_name'] == $view->name)) {
    if (arg(0) == 'show-all') {
      $view->pager['items_per_page'] = 200; //The number you want to have.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I try MYMODULE_views_pre_build and it's never firing up. To be sure that is not called, I create a txt file when this method is called

Comment: have you cleared the cache??

Comment: Yes I do. I'm using Omega 4. Is it possible that it could cause thé problem to not firing up thé prebuild hook

Comment: This has nothing to do with the theme you are using. Check about the function name and spelling. If your module is called "foo_mod" then the hook will be function foo_mod_views_pre_build(&$view) {}
Please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Views Flexible Pager module should solve this for you: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_flexible_pager